# MikroORM update coallesce

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sql-update, upsert, mikro-orm

In MikroORM, what would be the best/efficient way to implement update for specific values that are NOT NULL? For example, in Postgres there is the COALESCE() function:

`UPDATE some_table SET some_column = COALESCE(nullish_value, some_column) WHERE id = some_id;`

i.e. IF nullish_value === null THEN 'keep some_column' ELSE 'update nullish_value'.

Note, I believe this would be done in MySQL/MariaDB using IFNULL() and Oracle using NVL.

I understand the workaround could be done via code with a few extra calls. However, I'm looking for the best MikroORM-ish way to do things, for example, could it be done using @BeforeUpdate() or @BeforeUpsert() hooks in the Entity?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: FYI `COALESCE` is not a postgres specific feature, it's ANSI SQL, available in most (if not all) dialects.

Comment: Regarding your question, I am not entirely sure what answer you are looking for. You can run a raw query via `em.execute` or use the `raw` helper to set a raw value to an entity instance (and flush), both will work. Or of course, you can use hooks and handle this in code instead of db level.

Comment: @MartinAdámek, thanks! em.execute would certainly be the most efficient. However, I don't mind sacrificing that single db call for better type checking and offloading to the code. What would be the best way to implement this in MikroORM?